# Mattermost integration using slash command with Rasa

Tags: command, integration, slash, rasa, mattermost

I am new to RASA . Can anyone help me in integration rasa with Mattermost using slash command and not with Webhook.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [Rasa HTTP API](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/api/http-api/) or [Rasa X API](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa-x/api/rasa-x-http-api/) for that.

The general sequence will be-

1. Register the slash command.
2. Call Rasa HTTP API from slash command handler.
3. Convert response from Rasa into a Mattermost post if you need to.